# jQuery making a class to change background one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to background-color to change on hover for 6 different divs with the same class attached. How can I change the background-color on each individual div as I mouse in and out?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
   </div>
   <a href="#"><p id="caption">Thumbnail</p></a>
   <p id="date">Feburary 02, 2014</p>
</div>
```

(There are six of these.)

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.thumbnail').mouseover(function(){
    $('.thumbnail').css("background-color","#a84444")
});

$('.thumbnail').mouseout(function(){
    $('.thumbnail').css('background-color', '#EC5657')
});
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Webpage is: http://ljferris.com/portfolio_index/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this`. Here this refers the element which invoked the event

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbnail').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#a84444")
    });
    $('.thumbnail').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#EC5657')
    });
});
```

OR

You can simply use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), is shorthand for:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbnail').hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#a84444")
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#EC5657')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use another class 'div-one-bg' 'div-two-bg' and so on...

```
.div-one-bg:hover {
  background-color: #A84444 !important;
}
.div-one-bg {
  background-color: #EC5657;
}

.div-two-bg:hover {
    background-color: #AAFFCC !important;
}
.div-two-bg {
    background-color: #EE2277;
}
```

Then you can apply this class to you div like

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="thumbnail div-one-bg">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
   </div>
   <a href="#"><p id="caption">Thumbnail</p></a>
   <p id="date">Feburary 02, 2014</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="thumbnail div-two-bg">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
   </div>
   <a href="#"><p id="caption">Thumbnail</p></a>
   <p id="date">Feburary 02, 2014</p>
</div>
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp8ca/2/)